# storing values in union in c

Tags: c

If we have a union with three variables int i, char c, float f; and we store a value in say the variable c now. and we forget what is the variable of the union that holds a value currently, after some time. for this is there any mechanism provided by the language using which we can find out whether it is i or c or f that currently holds a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. The different members of a union all refer to the same memory adress, they are just different *ways of seeing* that memory. Modifiying a member of the union modifies all the other. You cannot distinguish one from another.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the point of the union is that *all* of them will hold a value.  The value you read might not make sense if you extract a different type than you put in, though.

You do have to keep track yourself of which type you put in if you intend to extract the same one.  There is no language feature to track the situation for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define VARIANT_FLOAT_TYPE 1
#define VARIANT_DOUBLE_TYPE 2
// and so on

struct variant_wb {
    union {
        float f;
        double d;
        int i;
        char c;
    };
    int stored_type;
};
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
struct variant_wb var;
var.f = 1.23;
var.stored_type = VARIANT_FLOAT_TYPE;
```

You could also make inumerous functions to deal with this struct/union, or you could learn C++ and do it "properly", since that language has this type of feature. My C++ is not very great, maybe some guru could show how to do a similar solution but in the C++ way.

Answer (score 2):

In C++/Qt/COM/DCOM there is the concept of a "Variant", that's roughly said a union which also stores how the union was accessed.
In C, you would have to provide something like this:

```
struct myCVariant
{
  int variantType;
  union 
  {
    char  v1;
    int   v2;
    float v3;
  } variantContent;

  void initVariant() 
  {
    variantType = 0;
  }

  void setChar(char a) 
  {
    variantType = 1;
    variantContent.v1 = a;
  }

  void setInt(int a)
  {
    variantType = 2;
    variantContent.v2 = a; 
  }

  // ... and so on

  bool getChar(char* pa)
  {
    if (variantType == 1)
    {
      *pa = variantContent.v1;
      return true;
    }

    return false; // Error reading a char where something else was stored
  }

  // ... and so on
};
```

You could copy some Variant implementation in some C++ source and port it to C. It's not completely the same, but it's similar. And it is somewhat typesafe (at least at runtime).

EDIT: hexa beat me by a second. And note, that I did not compile this, so my code might contain typos.

Comment: :P i'd say by 180 seconds! +1 for gmta

Comment: I missed the "See new answer bar", so for me it was just a second :-)

Answer (score 1):

No.

C is a lower-level language. It's allowing you to write whatever you want to raw memory. In the end, whether it contains text, integers, or code, all memory contains bits. There is no really way to determine what those bits represent.

While all union members will "hold a value", there's no mechanism to determine what data type it was originally.

If you need to know this, then you should either store a flag that indicates the data type, or you should not be using a union.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK if you forget because that is going to be written right there on the code and you can read it to find out.