# Cython: Conversion of a void* to a double and back-conversion

Tags: c, pointers, cython

to combine two independent C-written modules, i have to store a function pointer in a double array (pass it to the module), and convert it back later. 
I tried to stick to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35824907/4859499
However, i can't figure it out in Cython:

```
cdef void* ptr = getTestPtr() # getting the function pointer
cdef TEST mytest = <TEST> ptr # testing the function pointer
mytest()                      # still works here

cdef double** dPptr = <double**> ptr
cdef double* dPtr = dPptr[0]
doubleArrayStorage[0] = dPtr[0] #storing in a given double array at index 0
################################################

# starting of back conversion:
cdef double* dPtr2 = &doubleArrayStorage[0]
cdef void** Pptr2 = <void**> dPtr2
cdef void* ptr2 =  Pptr2[0]
cdef TEST mytest2 = <TEST> ptr2
mytest2()                         #SEGMENTATION FAULT !
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a function pointer to any other pointer type [is undefined behaviour in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559671/) so not guaranteed to work (see last point of the linked answer). In practice function pointer to `void*` is often OK. There is *no* good reason to store it as a pointer to a number though.

Looking at your code:

```
cdef void* ptr = getTestPtr() # getting the function pointer
cdef TEST mytest = <TEST> ptr # testing the function pointer
mytest()                      # still works here
```

You convert a function pointer to a void pointer and back to a function pointer. Probably OK, but not guaranteed.

```
cdef double** dPptr = <double**> ptr
```

Convert the function pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a double. Dodgy.

```
cdef double* dPtr = dPptr[0]
```

You de-reference the pointer. This gets you what is in the bit of memory the function is stored in (i.e. executable code). You pretend to interpret that executable code as a pointer to a double.

```
doubleArrayStorage[0] = dPtr[0] #storing in a given double array at index 0
```

`dPtr[0]` looks up an arbitrary bit of memory that it picks by misinterpreting some executable code as a pointer to a double. I'm surprised it doesn't segmentation fault here. Having got the contents of an arbitrary bit of memory you store it in the address pointed to by `doubleArrayStorage` (which you haven't told us about).

```
################################################

# starting of back conversion:
cdef double* dPtr2 = &doubleArrayStorage[0]
```

`&doubleArrayStorage[0]` reads from then takes the address of `doubleArrayStorage`. It's equivalent to just writing `doubleArrayStorage`. You save that as a double pointer. This is just the location of `doubleArrayStorage` (i.e. correctly a double pointer, but nothing to do with your original function).

```
cdef void** Pptr2 = <void**> dPtr2
```

You reinterpret the address of `doubleArrayStorage` as a pointer to a pointer to a void.

```
cdef void* ptr2 =  Pptr2[0]
```

You dereference that address. `ptr2` contains whatever is in the first element of `doubleArrayStorage` which you are pretending is a `void*`. In reality it's the contents of an arbitrary bit of memory you read earlier.

```
cdef TEST mytest2 = <TEST> ptr2
mytest2()                         #SEGMENTATION FAULT !
```

You use the contents of that arbitrary bit of memory as a function pointer and try to execute it.

---

In summary, I don't believe there's any way to do what you're trying to do safely in C (which means Cython can't do it either).