# storing any variable to void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to convert any variable to a void pointer and store the address as a number so I can later have access to the variable using the number as ID.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 123456789;
    void *ptr = &num;
    unsigned long addr = *(unsigned long *)ptr;
    printf("addr: %lu\n", addr);
    ptr = (void *)addr;
    num = (int)ptr;
    printf("num: %d\n", num);
}
```

Result:

```
addr: 17275796522765372693
num: 123456789
```

Is this a correct and safe way to do it? Will it also work with non-primitive variable types like struct?

Comment: "Is this a correct and safe way to do it?" - No. `"cast from pointer to integer of different size"` Essentially it is pointer abuse. If you need to store an `int` for later retrieval, use an `int` for storage.

Comment: Use `uintptr_t` to store an address as a number instead of `unsigned long`.  `#include <stdio.h>`.  But if it were me, I'd just pass around the `void*` as if it was a value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting double to void\* in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575340/converting-double-to-void-in-c)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The answer is no, of course, and it's a duplicate most likely, but it's technically not a duplicate of the linked question. The "*any variable*" here is not stored into a `void *ptr` but actually into the `unsigned long addr`, as confusing as the chosen names are.

Comment: The commonality is the mismatch between pointer and integer size (and here the cast between the two `num = (int)ptr;`) I see what you are saying, but a further discussion here of mismatch wouldn't add to what the other answer already provides.